# Synergy template won't run <script> code

Tags: javascript, html, templates, tags

While working on a project that uses the Synergy template from Themeforest (see http://themeforest.net/item/synergy-responsive-interactive-html-portfolio/3054099) I stumbled upon a problem.

In the html pages that make up the website, it is impossible for me to use script tags to run a piece of javascript code.
I need this code to generate email buttons, but it won't execute any of the code.

I've tried running

```
<script>
    alert('hi');
</script>
```

But it won't even run that.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or maybe a possible workaround?

TL;DR: Themeforest template won't let me run code in script tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe ask here? http://themeforest.net/item/synergy-responsive-interactive-html-portfolio/discussion/3054099?page=35

**I've found something about scripts:**

> for all of you using this theme, if you want to use Google Analytics
>   to track your site, you’ll notice the standard setup doesn’t track
>   your content pages, but only the index.html.
>
> In order to track all other pages and clicks, add this section in the
>   mc.module.animation javascript:
>
> /*----------------- start GA--------------------*/ (function ($) { //
>   Log all jQuery requests to Google Analytics
>   $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ if (typeof _gaq
>   !== "undefined" && _gaq !== null) { _gaq.push(['_trackPageview',
>   window.location.hash]); } }); })(jQuery); /*----------------- finish
>   GA --------------------*/ You also need to add the standard GA
>   javascript in the index.html (you don’t need to put it in the other
>   pages)

Comment: I've managed to solve the question by using onblur and onclick HTML instead of script tags.